# What the meaning of `!!` in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    a: "value",
    b: false
};
// nonexistent properties
console.log(!!obj.nonexistent);

// existing properties
console.log( !! obj.a);
```

i don't know the meaning of `!!`.

`console.log(obj.nonexistent); -> undefined`  I can understand this.
`console.log(!obj.nonexistent); -> true`      i cann't understand this.?????????

`console.log( !! obj.a);`                     i cann't understand this.?????????

Comment: Well I guess the last one shows *false* isn't it? ...instead of *undefined*...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: It means to apply `!` once, then apply it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, for example:

```
null  //null
```

then:

```
!null  //true
```

then:

```
!!null //false
```